# Does Pre-Glottalisation Occur with Voiceless Stops at Syllable Coda?

Tags: pronunciation, consonant-sounds

By ***voiceless stops*** I mean the following consonants:

> /p/  /k/  /t/

In the English way of pronunciation, these consonants, when occurring as the first segment in the coda, are articulated with a preceding glottal stop, e.g.

> *sit* will be pronounced as |siʔt|

I am wondering whether this phenomenon is present or not in German pronunciation?

Comment: Are you talking about British, i.e. UK, pronunciation of *sit*? // I think the answer to your question is no.

Answer (score 2):

There are two big problems with the global stop [ʔ]:

1. Most speakers are not aware of speaking it, and they are not aware of hearing it.
2. There is no letter (or combination of letters) that marks a global stop in a written word.

I am pretty sure, that (1) is the reason for (2), but that doesn't help to solve this problem. The non-awareness of that consonant even leads to a third problem:

3. Many dictionaries that use phonetic spelling often don't print that consonant, even if if is there.

In German we use the global stop at the beginning of a syllable that otherwise would start with a vowel:

- »[Apfel](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Apfel)« = [ˈʔapfl̩]
- »[Äpfel](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%84pfel)« (Plural of »Apfel«) = [ˈʔɛpfl̩]
- »[Uhr](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Uhr)« = [ʔuːɐ̯]
- »[beachten](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/beachten)« = [ˌbəˈʔaχtn̩]

If you follow the links in the examples above, you will see, that wiktionary notes the global stop only at *Apfel* and *beachten*, but [ʔ] is not printed in the phonetic spelling of »Äpfel« and »Uhr«, although the global stop is clearly hearable in all four examples.

I listened very carefully to the British and American pronunciation of »sit« at [dictionary.cambridge.org](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/pronunciation/english/sit): I do not hear a global stop in any of both versions. They sound different (the vowel is different) but in non of them I can hear a glottal stop, and when I speak those word, I don't feel anything in my glottis. I can feel the closing and opening of the glottis in *Apfel, Äpfel, Uhr* and *beachten* and of course at the beginning and in the middle of english *uh-oh*. But not in *sit*.

I think, in english there is no [ʔ] before [t] in »sit«, so I think your premise is wrong. And I can't hear or feel any glottal stop before the other voiceless stops neither in English nor in German.

But the voiceless stops [p], [t] and [k] have something else in common in English and German: They usually are aspirated, in both languages.

Take the German word »kalt« (*cold*) as an example. It is not spoken as [kalt] like [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/kalt) says. In fact it is:

- [kʰaltʰ]

with a little breathing sound after both stops. And I would say:

- »sit« = [sitʰ]

You definitely hear two sounds after the vowel [i] the first sound is the consonant [t] and then comes a short voiceless breathing sound, that is very similar to the pronunciation of the letter »h« for example in »here«. (Do not mix up [tʰ] with the english th-sounds [ð] and [θ]!)

---

But maybe you got aware of the short moment of silence between [i] and [t]? This is not an extra consonant. It is just the stop of airflow that precedes the explosive sound of [t]. It is a part of the [t]-sound.

In English the sounds [p], [t] and [k] are called *stops* just because of this interrupted airflow. In German those sounds are called »[Plosive](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plosiv)« because of the explossive sound after releasing the impound air.